# Displaying unicode string using opengl, qt and freetype

Tags: qt, opengl, unicode, freetype2

I want to display text in OGL using FTGL(wrapper for FreeType2) in Qt. I have problem with unicode->FTGL must have charcode of actually rendering char, to get glyph from truetype font, which is problematic when this char is for example one of: 'Zażółć gęślą jaźń'.

Do you have any ideas, why this code:

```
const unsigned char *string=(const unsigned char*)"POCZUJ GĘŚLĄ JAŹŃ";
// for multibyte - we can't rely on sizeof(T) == character
FTUnicodeStringItr<T> ustr(string);

for(int i = 0; (len < 0 && *ustr) || (len >= 0 && i < len); i++)
{
    unsigned int thisChar = *ustr++;
    unsigned int nextChar = *ustr;
    if(CheckGlyph(thisChar))
    {
        position += glyphList->Render(thisChar, nextChar,
                                      position, renderMode);
    }
}
```

works in Visual, but in Qt doesn't(it doesn't get proper charcodes, so it displays brackets)?

FTUnicodeStringItr template looks like this: http://www.nopaste.pl/11xt
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is, that C/C++ don't really support Unicode/wide characters in the source code. To be done properly you'd have to specify unicode characters either by `\uXXXX` escape sequences (if the compiler supports these), or by `\xXX\xXX` sequences building the code points from scratch. Visual C++ has wide character support (for the simple reason that all string manipulation in Windows is done in wide characters – don't confuse that with Unicode code points!).

I suggest you do the following: Qt has internationalization support built in. It boils down to define strings through the `tr(...)` helper function/macro with default language, i.e. english strings. Qt Linguist can then is used to create substitution rules, that are applied through the usage of `tr(...)` and does this with full Unicode support.

Comment: I don't think 'tr()' is my solution, I only want to get charcode of character in string. Besides I have read that to 'tr()' cannot be passed string as a variable. I manually made simple switch to get charcodes, but it didn't work for some characters causin' rest of the string to collapse(for example: 'Ó'). And I have second question- can I store those strings simply in std::string?

Comment: std::string doesn't go so well with Unicode. The problem is, that Unicode code points can have arbitrary length and certain control sequences cause characters to be merged. All this doesn't go so well with the way std::string manages its memory, so placing Unicode strings in std::string causes major headaches. QString has Unicode support, though. Also you must understand that in Unicode there are not just char codes, but so called *code points* on which certain combination rules apply. This goes so far that certain code point sequences will altoer and/or combine certain glyps from a font.

Comment: so I guess, I'll have to change passing strings by const char* to QString? And then, to obtain charcode,  `unsigned int( QString("this is mine stringen").at(0).toAscii() )` ?

Comment: In Unicode there are no charcodes. And you cannot convert it to ASCII, because that's the point of Unicode: Supporting things ASCII can't do. For example Unicode also defines sequences switching into right-to-left mode in the middle of the text.

Comment: Ok, this needs some further explanation: Unicode cannot be rendered by simply selecting characters from a font, drawing each and then incrementing the raster position. Since Unicode has glyph composition, and run control sequences one needs a layout stage, that first processes the whole Unicode string into glyphs and their final position. Such a layout engine is Pango or what Qt has built in. To properly draw Unicode text you must go through such a layout engine. This engine gives you a stream of glyph codes (which can be passed to Freetype) and glyph positions.